# post SVG information on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an svg with just `3 paths` containing the following id's: `main`,`second`, `third`  and  I am trying to send their ID to my NodeJS back end script.

The Idea is that I capture the `svg element id` on click and `post` it to my back end where I can consume it and pair it with a json file.

> My issue is that I am not sending the element's id but the whole svg's ID

Here is my html:

```
<body ng-app="">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="second.html">Page 2</a></button>
    <div class="boundaries">
    <!-- SVG -->
    <div ng-include="'map.svg'" id="map"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my jQuery script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#map', function () {
        var map_value = this.id; 
        $.post("/foo", function(map_value){
        console.log( "SVG Element Selected:", map_value );
        });
    });
});
```

My SVG path's id : `main`, `second`, `third`.

I think the problem is in the way I am trying to capture my `SVG element's` ID on click `var map_value = this.id;` but I am unsure how to capture it otherwise.

Comment: You are catching click events on your div element only here, so what exactly did you expect? And even if you could rely on event bubbling here, you would have to at least check the original event target. // Not sure how `ng-include="'map.svg'"` works, exactly - but if that only embeds the SVG as an `object` or `img` element, you might not have access to the elements inside it to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

What if your try to get the targeted element from the event parameter (I didn't try this code, just from my head)

```
$(document).on('click', '#map', function (e) {
    var map_value = e.target.id;
    // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: and how do I pass i to my post request?

Comment: your code should work as it is right now, isn't it ?

Comment: the answer is correct but I am just wondering why passing the `e` argument inside the function actually fixes the problem? Can you please explain?

Comment: `this` is set to the element that the event handler was registered to. In your case, that is the document.  However `e.target` is the element that was actually clicked on.